# Asking Prime number

Tags: python, numbers

I tried to see what is Prime number in number 2 ~ 12 , and I wrote some codes.
But after '3', it only prints 'Not Prime number' even if '11' is there.
What is the problem?

```
a=True
for n in range(2,13):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i ==0:
            a=False
        if a == False:
        print(n, ": Not prime.")
    else:
        print(n,": Prime")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You'll also want to read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11082165)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset `a` to `True` for each now value. Also `a == False` is just `not a` (as `if a==True` is `if a`)

```
for n in range(2,13):
    a = True
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i ==0:
            a = False
    if not a:
        print(n, ": Not prime.")
    else:
        print(n,": Prime")
```

---

Some advices about the loop

- stop at the square root of the number
- use a `break` to stop looping after knowing it's false
- use the `for/else`, if no break has been found it goes into the `else`

```
for n in range(2,13):
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n % i ==0:
            print(n, ": Not prime.")
            break
    else:
        print(n,": Prime")

2 : Prime
3 : Prime
4 : Not prime.
5 : Prime
6 : Not prime.
7 : Prime
8 : Not prime.
9 : Not prime.
10 : Not prime.
11 : Prime
12 : Not prime.
```