# Prime number function returning all numbers, not only primes

Tags: python

I have two versions of a function: each one does part of what I want but I cannot implement everything in a single function. I am not seeing where the disconnect is.

I tried to deduce this in a [different post for the formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66002338/rotate-through-list-of-delimiters-in-join/66002449#66002449) as a simple example while also referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61060896/asking-prime-number). When plugging in to my function though, I cannot figure it out.

The first version has the intended format but returns all numbers, not only the primes.

```
def primeNumbersBetweenInterval(x, y):
    """ Display all the prime numbers within an interval """

    # Set lower and upper values from both inputted values
    lower = min(x, y)
    upper = max(x, y)
    num_range = range(lower, upper + 1)
    formats = ['#', '$', '%']

    for num in num_range:
       # all prime numbers are greater than 1
       if num > 1:
            for i in range(2, num):
                if (num % i) == 0:
                    break
            else:
                num_delimited = ''.join(str(j)+formats[i%len(formats)] for i,j in enumerate(num_range))[:-1]
            return num_delimited

# Calling either way produces same result
# primeNumbersBetweenInterval(11, 27)
primeNumbersBetweenInterval(27, 11)

# have: 11#12$13%14#15$16%17#18$19%20#21$22%23#24$25%26#27
# all numbers in range, not only prime
# want: 11#13$17%19#23
```

The second version has the primes but outputted as ints and I cannot get them formatted as hoped.

```
def primeNumbersBetweenInterval(x, y):
    """ Display all the prime numbers within an interval """

    # Set lower and upper values from both inputted values
    lower = min(x, y)
    upper = max(x, y)
    num_range = range(lower, upper + 1)
    formats = ['#', '$', '%']

    for num in num_range:
       # all prime numbers are greater than 1
       if num > 1:
            for i in range(2, num):
                if (num % i) == 0:
                    break
            else:
                print(num)

# Calling either way produces same result
# primeNumbersBetweenInterval(11, 27)
primeNumbersBetweenInterval(27, 11)

# have: 11
#       13
#       17
#       19
#       23
# so correct numbers but not formatted
# want: 11#13$17%19#23 (on one row formatted like above)
```

Comment: You're always returning on the first iteration. And `num_delimited` contains all the numbers in the range regardless of whether they're prime.

Comment: Well, of course, you build your string with `enumerate(num_range)`. That will enumerate all the numbers in your `range`

Comment: Actually it will skip the first number because it was used up by `for num in num_range:`.

Comment: `range()` returns a generator object, not a list, so you can't iterate over the same range multiple times.

Comment: I suppose then what I need to figure out is how to output my ints as a list where the join() logic can be used. That is what I am not getting how to implement in the latter effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step one: Move the logic for prime testing to a standalone function.

```
def is_prime(num):
    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            break
    else:
        return True
    return False
```

Step two: Invoke that logic and build your formatted string

```
def primeNumbersBetweenInterval(x, y):
    """ Display all the prime numbers within an interval """

    # Set lower and upper values from both inputted values
    lower = min(x, y)
    upper = max(x, y)
    num_range = range(lower, upper + 1)
    formats = ['#', '$', '%']
    primes = ""
    count = 0

    for num in num_range:
       # all prime numbers are greater than 1
       if is_prime(num):
           if len(primes) == 0:
               primes = str(num)
           else:
               primes = f"{primes}{formats[count%3]}{num}"
           count = count + 1
    print(primes)
```

Tested to (as requested) output

```
11#13$17%19#23
```

Comment: Well, that is way cleaner than what I had. Works great. I also added a `print` statement for when there are no primes.